# Symmetric Gauss Seidel iteration

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Let $A=L+D+R$,
where $L$ is a strict lower triangular, $D$ a diagonal and $R$ an strict upper triangular matrix.

Consider the symmetric Gauss Seidel iteration:

\begin{align*}
(L+D)x^{(k+1/2)}+Rx^{(k)}&=b \\
Lx^{(k+1/2)}+(D+R)x^{(k+1)}&=b
\end{align*}

How can I show that this iteration is consistent? My idea is to plug in the solution $x$ into $x^{(k)}$ and try to get the same solution $x$ into $x^{(k+1)}$, but I am having trouble with this.

Comment: I suppose you want to solve $Ax=b$?

Comment: yes, that's correct

Answer (score 4):

This is probably not the best thing to do if you only want to show consistency. But it is also useful for other purposes such as convergence analysis.

First, modify your equations to arrive at:
$$ x^{(k+1/2)} = x^k + (D+L)^{-1}(b-Ax^k),$$
$$ x^{(k+1)} = x^{(k+1/2)} + (D+R)^{-1}(b-Ax^{(k+1/2)}).$$
Then plugging the first equation into the second one yields:
\begin{array}
&x^{(k+1)} 
& = x^k + \{(D+L)^{-1} + (D+R)^{-1} - (D+R)^{-1}A(D+L)^{-1}\} (b-Ax^k) \\
& = x^k + (D+R)^{-1}D(D+L)^{-1} (b-Ax^k).
\end{array}
This directly implies that $x^{(k+1)}=x^k$ if $b-Ax^k=0$.

Answer (score 3):

You can take the actual solution $x=x^{(k)}$ and get
$$(L+D)x^{(k+1/2)} + Rx= b = (L+D+R)x.$$
If $L+D$ is invertible (it has to be, else the algorithm will not work), you get $x=x^{(k+1/2)}$. The same argument will now apply to the second equation, thus you will get $x=x^{(k+1)}$.

By subtracting the two equations, you can prove that if $x^{(k)}=x^{(k+1)}$ you have
$Ax^{(k)}=b$.

Comment: Since you are new, note that you can accept answers and vote helpful answers up.

Comment: I tried to vote up, but for some reason it says I need a total of 15 reputations,,,not sure what it means

Comment: @Rocky78 for you to accept there is no need to be 15 reputation, just mark the answer as correct, this is below the downvote and just shows up for you. When you click in there became green and it looks like an teachers mark of correct.